# background-image relative url doesnt work in CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am keeping my both html and css stylesheet files in the same folder and images in a `img` folder.

Relative links to images works on html:

```
<img src="img\Philippines.png">
```

but it doesn't work in css when i write:

```
#Philippines {
background-image:url("../img/UK.png");
```

it does work when i put full url:

```
#Philippines {
background-image:url("file:///C:/Users/User/Dropbox/+HOROS%20code/img/Philippines.png");
```

I want it to work with relative urls, any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`url()` in CSS is relative to the location of your CSS file.

If I understand you correctly, this is your folder structure:

```
-+-img
 |  +--images
 +html_file
 +css_file
```

If so, try this:

```
#Philippines {
    background-image:url("img/UK.png");
}
```