# Set path to background image with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set a background image with JQuery, but I have a problem with fisical location of the image. For example, I set the image background from a js document with this code:

```
$('.flat-icon').css('background-image', 'url("' + 'flatmask/images/Preloader_1.gif")');
```

When I am in the directory, The background is loaded. But when I move mu html file to other directory, then I include the js and I want to set the background code, the background is not set. I seems like the `.css()` Query function search the image relative to the route of the html document where is included, not like the css `background-image: url()`, I see it search the image relative to the CSS document. How can I set the image from diferent documents without change the path in the `.css()` function?

Comment: yes, you are correct. you have to specify an absolute path (if you want to use the same code within different directories) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500594/background-image-relative-url-doesnt-work-in-css-stylesheet

Comment: How can I pass the route through a parameter like `$('.class').myFunction(){parameter:value}` ???

Comment: Only if you write a method (extension to the library). Doing something like this would be a lot easier : `myFunction('.class', value)` - writing a basic function and passing some parameters.

Comment: Many thanks, I go to implement this